# TouchListener onTouchEvent not called

Tags: android

I have a custom view which i am adding to relative layout and adding touch Listener to the 
custom view only.The problem is  onTouchevent is not called.Plz help
    sample code from my actual code::

```
ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.base); //relative layout
base.addView(move);
move.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("onTouch v","="+v);
            if(v instanceof MovingView) {
                return false;
            }
            else 
                return true;
        }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();


}
};// close listener
```

Comment: You need to clean up your question-  you're talking about the click listener, but then using touchListeners, which are not the same.  You also have an onTouchEvent function in the listener which will never be called, because the right name is onTouch and everything needs to be done there.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt to call onTouchEvent()

Comment: what is in your move variable means which view. ya use onClickListener

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Sorry for the typo.. It was ontouch.....@eskimoapps onTouchEvent() is not called automatically??

Comment: No, onTouch() is automatically called because it is part of the class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: onTouch is called i cans see the Logs My problem is onTouchEven is not called..

Comment: @KingCobraa move is a custom view.

Comment: do one thing  just directly implement your touch listener to the class and set move.setontouchListener(this); and @override these methodes.

Comment: @KingCobraa i implemented wat u said .. now whole screen has become touchable . if i'm clicking anywhere on screen my view is moving.whereas i want to touch only view.

Comment: This probably means that your customView is covering whole area of the screen.

Comment: @Marek i have set the layout params for the custome view..It is displayed properly

Comment: did you try my answer that is below?

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, you set the listener before initializing it (it is null). Try this:

```
ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.base); //relative layout
base.addView(move);

OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("onTouch v","="+v);
            if(v instanceof MovingView) {
                return false;
            }
            else 
                return true;
        }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();


}
};// close listener

move.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Secondly, be aware that:

> "onTouchEvent() method is called
>   when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under
>   it."

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: what about adding @Override before each method?

Comment: I am not able to  add @Override on onTouchEvent.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the docs and mentioning it is not called when child views are handling it.